# How to EXECUTE a set of stored procedures in a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql, execute

I have a table that stores names of stored procedures in my file structure. The idea is that the calling stored procedure will be given `@in_Strings` as a parameter; these are the display names of the stored procedures I want to execute.

Then, I want to search my table of stored procedures and execute the ones whose display names match with the inputted set.

For example, the calling stored procedure may be given an input set of strings 'foo', 'bar', and 'baz'. That means I want to be able to execute 'dbo.foo_sproc','dbo.bar_sproc', and 'dbo.baz_sproc'.

I am using SQL Server 2012. Any ideas?

BTW, my stored procedures table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SPROCS
(
    Display_Name NVARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    SPROC_Name NVARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    CreatedDateTime DATETIME2(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT GETUTCDATE()
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL, like [in paqogomez's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005144/297408), but, unlike any other kind of names, procedure names can be parametrised in SQL Server, and so dynamic SQL is not necessary in this case.

For instance, if this was about a single procedure, you could read and execute the matching name using this simple method:

```
DECLARE @SPROC_Name nvarchar(256);

SELECT @SPROC_Name = SPROC_Name
FROM dbo.SPROCS
WHERE Display_Name = @in_string;

EXECUTE @SPROC_Name;
```

Just like that.

Since you are mentioning a *set* of strings, however, you will need a cursor to loop through the result set of matching procedure names and pass each name to the EXECUTE statement.

```
DECLARE @SPROC_Name nvarchar(256);

DECLARE procnames CURSOR
    LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY STATIC READ_ONLY
FOR
    SELECT @SPROC_Name = SPROC_Name
    FROM dbo.SPROCS
    WHERE ... /* condition involving Display_Name and @in_string */
;

OPEN procnames;
FETCH NEXT FROM procnames INTO @SPROC_Name;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXECUTE @SPROC_Name;
    FETCH NEXT FROM procnames INTO @SPROC_Name;
END;

CLOSE procnames;
DEALLOCATE procnames;
```

Comment: Ok makes a lot of sense. Just wondering, would we be able to use a loop instead of a cursor?

Comment: @sahibeast: I'm not sure what you mean. When you use a cursor, you typically always use a loop – to go through the result set returned by the cursor row by row. Did you mean using a loop *without* a cursor?

Comment: @Andriy M: Yes sorry. That I what I meant. Using a loop to parse the result set without a cursor.

Comment: @sahibeast: Well, it may be possible to use a loop and emulate a cursor without actually using the cursor syntax, but why would you want to do that? In SQL you process data in sets, and cursors are exactly the tool for when you *have to* process data row by row instead of sets. There's absolutely no need to re-invent the wheel. If you don't need a cursor, it usually means you don't need a loop either (which is good, because that is the normal situation in SQL).

Comment: My existing codebase already uses loops instead of cursors. So although I agree that cursors are technically better style, I still want to use loops for consistency's sake.

Answer (score 1):

A sql server example:

A cursor can loop through your result set and execute your stored procedures.

This (simple, but untested) script loops every sproc in the @in_strings variable.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getSprocs @in_Strings varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql varchar(max)
    DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
    SELECT SPROC_Name
    FROM dbo.SPROCS
    where sproc_name in (@in_Strings)

    OPEN db_cursor   
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
    BEGIN   
        set @sql = 'exec ' + @name
        exec @sql
        FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   
    END   

    CLOSE db_cursor   
    DEALLOCATE db_cursor
END
```